# is there a way to bulk load XML using psycopg2 copy_from?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have an XML file like this:

```xml
<Library>
  <Book id="123">
    <Title>Python Does Everythig</Title>
    <Author>Smith</Author>
  </Book>

  <Book id="456">
    <Title>Postgres is Neat</Title>
    <Author>Wesson</Author>
  </Book>
</Library>
```

and I've got a nice little python program that uses XSL to convert the XML into a pipe-delimited format, and then bulk load it using `psycopg2.copy_from`, creating one record per book.  All is well.

But I would also like to add the actual XML that was used to create the book record to the book record itself.  In other words, I want my book table to look like:

```
create table book (
    id       integer      not null primary key,
    title    varchar(100) not null,
    author   varchar(100) not null,
    xml_data xml          not null
);
```

If I was using SQL to insert the rows, it's simple enough:  I would just use  `XMLPARSE ( CONTENT ?)`.

Is there a way to do the equivalent when using `copy_from`?

Comment: I'd even settle for a way to get the XML of the current node in my XSL sheet, should someone know that (value-of seems to strip out the XML tags, which makes sense).  If I could store the XML on the first pass, I could do post-processing to create the structured value.

Answer (score 0):

Copy_from wraps the PostgreSQL bulk COPY statements and this is not supports (csv is supported by the way).

To be honest, I would just parse the XML in your app, and then send the data in to the db.